# How to get meta values in reactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react application.I need meta tags value(description,title,etc).I am not able to access it.I need for navigator share api.My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.getOpenGraphData = this.getOpenGraphData.bind(this);
  }
  getOpenGraphData(property){
        return document.querySelector(`meta[property="${property}"]`)
            .getAttribute('content');
    }

  handleClick(){
    navigator.share({
      title: getOpenGraphData('og:title'),
      text: getOpenGraphData('og:description'),
      url: getOpenGraphData('og:url')
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Successfully shared');
    alert("successfully shared")
})
  .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing:', error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button content='Click Here' onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But i am not able to access meta properties.Where I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not with selecting the meta tag, but with **navigator.share()** as it is an experimental feature not fully supported by all browsers, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share).

You can check if navigator is supported before calling it:

```
if (navigator.share) {
    navigator.share({...});
}
```